# How to write that Lyapunov function?

Tags: differential-equations

For didactic purpose I investigate the stability of the ODEs system `{x'[t] == x[t] + y[t], y'[t] == -5 x[t] - 2 y[t]}`.

Its stream plot

```
StreamPlot[{x + y, -5 x - 2 y}, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}]
```

[image]

clearly shows a spiral sink at the origin.

How to prove it, making use of Lyapunov function?
First of all, how to explicitly write down that [Lyapunov function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LyapunovFunction.html) for the system under consideration with help of `LyapunovSolve`?
I don't find it [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?page=1&tab=Relevance&q=Lyapunov). The first example in the Applications section of [the documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LyapunovSolve.html)
to `LyapunovSolve` is useful, but it produces the conclusion, not a Lyapunov function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe this?:

```
ClearAll[v, x, y];
a = CoefficientArrays[{x + y, -5 x - 2 y}, {x, y}] // Last;
p = LyapunovSolve[Transpose[a], -IdentityMatrix[2]];
v[x_, y_] =  p . {x, y} . {x, y} // Simplify (* Lyapunov function *)

(* Check "energy dissipation" dv/dt *)
Dt[v[x, y]] /. Thread[Dt[{x, y}] -> {x + y, -5 x - 2 y}] // Simplify
```

> ```
> (*  1/6 (32 x^2 + 14 x y + 5 y^2)  -- Lyapunov function *)
>
> (*  -x^2 - y^2  -- dv/dt is neg. def. *)
> ```

Comment: As usually, very good.

Comment: @Michael E2 could you do this to find a Lyapunov function for "any" system?

Comment: @Math I doubt it. It fails on this: `{x'[t] == x[t]^3 + y[t], y'[t] == -5 x[t] - 2 y[t]^3}`. But it succeeds here: `ode = {x'[t] == Sin[x[t]] + y[t], y'[t] == -5 x[t] - 2 Sin[y[t]]};
vf = First@SolveValues[ode, {x'[t], y'[t]}];
a = D[vf, {{x[t], y[t]}}] /. {x[t] -> 0, y[t] -> 0};
p = LyapunovSolve[Transpose[a], -IdentityMatrix[2]];
v[x_, y_] = p . {x, y} . {x, y} // Simplify`. I don't think there's any guarantee that there exists a quadratic Lyapunov function.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thank you! Can you please have a look at this question: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/265288/constructing-a-lyapunov-function-for-this-system

Answer (score 3):

Stability of `{x',y'}]== f[x,y]` can be investigated by searching for critical points of `f` (see e.g: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stability_theory). In your case this is obvious {0,0}. Then in the general case `f` is linearized at the critical points, again in your case that is not needed, as f is already linear. Then the `Eigensystem` is

```
mat= m = {{1, 1}, {-5, -2}};
{x'[t], y'[t]} = mat . {x[t], y[t]}
{eigenval, eigenvec}=Eigensystem[{{1, 1}, {-5, -2}}] // N

{-0.5 + 1.65831 I, -0.5 - 1.65831 I}, {{-0.3 - 0.331662 I, 
   1.}, {-0.3 + 0.331662 I, 1.}}}
```

The stability depends on the real parts of the eigenvalues. In your case `mat` is real, what makes the 2 eigenvalues conjugate complex and there is only one real part of -0.5.

If the real part is negative, as in your case, we have an attractive critical point, called a sink. As the imaginary part is different from zero, it is a spiral sink. The trajectory will approach zero the faster, the larger the absolute value of the eigenvalue.

Comment: Sorry, this is not it. The question is about the construction of Lyapunov function with help of Mathematica. Hope I am and was clear.

Comment: You have a very simple problem that does not need the Liapunov coefficient. This coefficient is needed if you want to investigate  the rate of separation of infinitesimally close trajectories. .The Liapunov theory is more evolved than the simple stability analysis.